# iAd in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad

What would be the best way to integrate iAd in Sprite Kit? I am currently doing this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  CGRect bannerRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 320, 50);
  ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:bannerRect];
  [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

The ad is shown at the bottom of the screen perfectly, but by doing this, the ADBannerView is hiding the bottom part of my game. I'd just like to resize the SKScene to be shown above the iAd container.

Thanks for any help! It is greatly appreciated :)

PS.
The code for creating the SKScene:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  // Configure the view.
  SKView *skView = (SKView *)[self view];
  [skView setShowsFPS:YES];
  [skView setShowsNodeCount:YES];
  [skView setShowsPhysics:NO];

  // Create and configure the scene.
  MainMenuScene *mainMenuScene = [MainMenuScene sceneWithSize:[skView bounds].size];
  [mainMenuScene setScaleMode:SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill];
  [skView presentScene:mainMenuScene];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to resize the scene only while the banner is shown? Otherwise just design your scene so that there is nothing (important) obstructed by the banner, except maybe for the background image.

Comment: I originally wanted to resize the SKScene and have SKScene and ADBannerView side by side as subviews. But I may just move the content in the bottom part of the scene up [iAd-height] points. This seems like an ok solution, thanks!